# What is the difference between assigning an IIFE's public members to a variable vs returning an object

Tags: javascript, iife

I've been looking at a lot of JavaScript code lately and I've seen two different ways of using assigning "public" properties of IIFE's.

The first is to create a variable and assign that variable to a property inside of the IIFE like so:

```
var public1;

(function(){
    var foo= "Foo", bar= "Bar";

    public1= {
        getFoo: function(){
            return foo;
        }
    };
}());
```

The second way I see is returning an object from the IIFE like so:

```
var public2 = (function(){
    var foo2= "Foo2", bar2= "Bar2";

    return {
        getBar: function(){
            return bar2;
        }
    };
}());
```

Is there a fundamental difference between these two ways or is it just a matter of preference? I've also created a fiddle so you can run or update the code if you'd like: [http://jsfiddle.net/bittersweetryan/gnh79/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/bittersweetryan/gnh79/4/)

Comment: IIFE = Immediately Invoking Function Expression, I assume. I honestly have never heard of this term or abbreviation (which does not mean anything). Though I think *immediate* or *self-invoking function* are more common.

Comment: @Felix: [Here's an article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) that discusses IIFE, and the reason for the name. *"I’m proposing the term “Immediately-Invoked Function Expression”, and “IIFE” if you like acronyms....because it’s not the function that’s executing itself, even though the function is being executed"*

Comment: @patrick: Thank you, much appreciated! I think I'm just not such a fan of acronyms ;) :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference.

But I'd argue that the second one is a bit easier to maintain. When you change the variable name in the first example, you have to change it in the function as well.

Comment: The only good reason I can see for the first case other is the convention of declaring variables at the top of their scope. In the second case the IIFE is explicitly associated with the related variable so much more obvious what is going on, that is a more important criterion IMHO. :-)