# How should I declare my self-calling function?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I've seen self-calling functions in Javascript written like this:

```
(function () {
    // foo!
})();
```

But I've also seen them written like this:

```
(function () {
    // bar!
}());
```

Syntactically, they do exactly the same thing. My personal habit is the first format, actually, but is there any difference between the two that I should be aware of? Like browser kinks or whatever?

One very trivial thing, for example, is if the second format should work reliably, then it would mean that something like this should be possible as well:

```
function () {
    // shut the front door! saved two characters right there!
}();
```

It hurts readability a good deal though.

Comment: i think this subject has been discussed more then enough, a little search on SO should have gave you the right answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7197480/401137

Comment: I always use your first construction and it works without fault.  I believe the second will also work.  The third will not work in all cases because the interpreter needs to know the difference between an expression and a function definition in some contexts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Location of parenthesis for auto-executing anonymous JavaScript functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions)

Comment: @Dementic ~ sorry about that. I *did* do a search, but I guess I didn't get hits because of differences in terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First:

There is, like you assumed, absolutely no difference between the first two version of your self-invoking anonymous function. No browser klinks, quirks, just comes down to personal preference (Douglas Crockford calls the latter form "dog balls" by the way).

Second:

```
function() {
}()
```

will not work by design, since that statement creates a *function statement/declaration*. You need a *function expression* to immediately invoke itself. To create a function expression you can do multiple things. Putting the whole statement into parenthesis is one way, but you could also write

```
!function() {
}()
```

or

```
+function() {
}
```

All of these operators will make an expression.

Comment: @Amaan — Because in that context it is a function expression, not a function declaration. Function declarations aren't allowed there.

Comment: @Quentin: as far as I know, a function statement is just differnt wording for function declaration.

Comment: function declarations can't exist inside parentheses.  For more detail see here: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: @Andre ~ I didn't even see the function declaration syntax happening. Shame, shame.

Comment: @Amaan In that case the function is a _named function expression_. See http://kangax.github.com/nfe/

Answer (score 1):

The first two are identical, but if I remember correctly, one of them is preferred by jsLint (I think it’s the second).

The third raises a [syntax error](http://jsfiddle.net/MwrCL/) in most interpreters, but there are other variants:

```
!function() {
    alert('I’m executing myself!');
}();

var noname = function() {
    alert(noname); // undefined!
}();
```

​
You can replace the `!` with a `+` or `-` ( None of them will make Crockford happy )

Comment: TIL about `!` `+` and `-` forcing a statement. And yup, those won't make me happier either, but supposedly useful for minification / obfuscation, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a convention issue.

`(function () {}());` <- one less stack frame before execution (maybe)

`(function () {})();` <- executed outside the parenthesis, so one tiny little frame before execution, although I don't like this style, IMO it's visually disconnected.

`function () {}();` <strike><- this is just bad practice IMO, it's not immediately obvious that this is an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) which is mostly due to convention, but this also has the problem that if you forget a semi-colon before the expression it will, under some conditions silently assign variables the value undefined.</strike>

Example:

```
var x = 0,
    y = 1,
    z = 3,

function () {
    alert("Z is now undefined, instead of throwing a syntax error.");
}();
```

As mentioned by Andre Meinhold, this is not in expression position.

Answer (score 0):

Pragmatically speaking, JSLint will complain about the first and prefer the second format. Beyond that, it's really personal preference and consistency is key here.

The third format will result in a SyntaxError, so you can't use that. That's because your creating a function declaration, not a function expression. It's the function expression that you're calling when you use the immediate function pattern.

Answer (score 0):

[Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) says to use `(function () {...}())`.

It's just a stylistic choice, but it's in the community's interest to agree upon a convention and (at the risk of starting a flame-war) why not use Crockford's?

Answer (score 0):

Also, keep in mind that `(function () { }());` adds potential confusion. Since in a long function, someone not paying attention might see two closing parentheses and only one being opened.

Comment: And this is exactly why I ask, even if the thing seems soooo trivial. Right after reading @ethagnawl's answer, I read yours. Such is the developer environment, I guess.